# creating custom framework and using it to other prjects leading to crash

Tags: swift, frameworks

All i am working to create a modular application each of the module will be embeded as framework in main project. the thing is when i drag and drop my framework to the project and run it. the application crash with below mention error. tried all the possible help available but no luck. please figure-out if anyone can. thankyou

error:

```
dyld: dyld cache load error: shared cache file open() failed
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Referenced from: /Users/targetpk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43472599- 
DD49-4EC3-9AF7-7D23E8AEA601/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3F83C3FB-C46F-400C- 
88A5-0BE86BBA3B9D/testFrameWork.app/Frameworks/WorkSpace.framework/WorkSpace
Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent librarie DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/targetpk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20F71/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4.18D46
```

Comment: Did you import also Alamofire? It seems that your framework uses it?

Comment: yes it was added as pod in framework.

Comment: Try `EmbedAndSign` when dragging the framework into project.

Comment: Also, can you please guide me how did you installed a pod inside your framework? I tried a lot, but wasn't able to install.